# Redefinition and Enumerator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums

I'm having a problem with enumerators. Let's not waste anyone's time, and get straight to it. The error:

```
1> forgelib\include\forge\socket.h(79): error C2365: 'RAW' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
1>          forgelib\include\forge\socket.h(66) : see declaration of 'RAW'
```

The code:

```
namespace Forge {
    enum SocketType {
        STREAM       = SOCK_STREAM,      // Sequenced, reliable, 2-way
        DGRAM        = SOCK_DGRAM,       // Connectionless, unreliable
        RAW          = SOCK_RAW,         // Raw protocol
        RDM          = SOCK_RDM,         // Reliable-delivered message
        SEQPACKET    = SOCK_SEQPACKET    // Sequenced, reliable, 2-way
    };
    enum ProtocolType {
        IP           = IPPROTO_IP,       // IPv4
        ICMP         = IPPROTO_ICMP,     // Internet Control Messsage Protocol
        IGMP         = IPPROTO_IGMP,     // Internet Group Management Protocol
        GGP          = IPPROTO_GGP,      // Gateway to Gateway Protocol
        TCP          = IPPROTO_TCP,      // Transmission Control Protocol
        PUP          = IPPROTO_PUP,      // PARC Universal Packet Protocol
        UDP          = IPPROTO_UDP,      // User Datagram Protocol
        IDP          = IPPROTO_IDP,      // Xerox NS Protocol
        RAW          = IPPROTO_RAW,      // Raw IP Packets
        IPV6         = IPPROTO_IPV6      // IPv6
    };
}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot have equal names in old c-style enums. If you have C++11 - you can use `enum class`, static constants in classes, different namespaces, or you can simply use different names.

Example with `enum classes`

```
enum class SocketType
{
   RAW = SOCK_RAW
};

enum class ProtocolType
{
   RAW = IP_PROTO_RAW
};
```

example with `constants`

```
struct SocketType
{
   static const int RAW = SOCK_RAW;
};

struct ProtocolType
{
   static const int RAW = IP_PROTO_ROW;
};
```

Comment: So I have to rename one of them despite them being in different enumerators? How stupid is that. Stupid language. Thank you.

Comment: No, you do not have to rename them. The solution is in his answer.

Comment: @JesseBrands: Imagine the language would accept your construct, what would the line `int x = RAW;` do exactly?

Comment: I think I understand where he's coming from entirely. I would expect the line `int x = RAW;` to be invalid syntax. I would personally expect it to read `int x = SocketType::RAW;` or `int x = Forge::SocketType::RAW;`

Answer (score 5):

`Forge::RAW` is ambiguous, it is not knows if this is from which enum type.

Use this style:

```
namespace Forge {
    namespace SocketType {
      enum Values {
        STREAM       = SOCK_STREAM,      // Sequenced, reliable, 2-way
        DGRAM        = SOCK_DGRAM,       // Connectionless, unreliable
        RAW          = SOCK_RAW,         // Raw protocol
        RDM          = SOCK_RDM,         // Reliable-delivered message
        SEQPACKET    = SOCK_SEQPACKET    // Sequenced, reliable, 2-way
      };
    }
    namespace  ProtocolType {
      enum Values {
        IP           = IPPROTO_IP,       // IPv4
        ICMP         = IPPROTO_ICMP,     // Internet Control Messsage Protocol
        IGMP         = IPPROTO_IGMP,     // Internet Group Management Protocol
        GGP          = IPPROTO_GGP,      // Gateway to Gateway Protocol
        TCP          = IPPROTO_TCP,      // Transmission Control Protocol
        PUP          = IPPROTO_PUP,      // PARC Universal Packet Protocol
        UDP          = IPPROTO_UDP,      // User Datagram Protocol
        IDP          = IPPROTO_IDP,      // Xerox NS Protocol
        RAW          = IPPROTO_RAW,      // Raw IP Packets
        IPV6         = IPPROTO_IPV6      // IPv6
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd think it could make a distinction between Forge::SocketType::RAW and Forge::ProtocolType::RAW... but apparently C++ is still in the stone age.

Comment: Actually, it's not, you just chose not to use enum classes.

Comment: Using C++11 is not an option for this project. But Piotr's answer will do, thanks!

Comment: @JesseBrands so who's in the stone age? C++ has been in the bronze age for a full two years now :-)

Comment: @JesseBrands: It can do, however by using non-class enums you declare the identifiers `Forge::RAW` and `Forge::RAW` too.

Comment: @JesseBrands Really, saying "the language is too old" and "we do not use the new form of the language" at the same time is ... interesting.

Comment: @Angew I'm not a fan of C++ either way. But since C++11 support isn't just there yet, we went with Stone Age C++. Oh well, thanks anyway.