# Problems comparing value to member of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, comparison, constants

**This question is a follow up on:**
[Redefinition and Enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772253/redefinition-and-enumerator/16772314)

My C++ compiler gives the following warning and error:

```
1>forgelib\source\socket.cpp(145): warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'Forge::AddressFamily'
1>          forgelib\include\forge\socket.h(70) : see declaration of 'Forge::AddressFamily'
1>forgelib\source\socket.cpp(145): error C2275: 'Forge::AddressFamily' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          forgelib\include\forge\socket.h(70) : see declaration of 'Forge::AddressFamily'
1>forgelib\source\socket.cpp(145): error C2228: left of '.INet' must have class/struct/union
```

This is socket.cpp(145):

```
void Forge::InternetHost::validHostEntity(hostent* he) {
    if (he->h_addrtype != AddressFamily.INet || he->h_length != 4) { // <--145
        throw new Forge::SocketException("Address family mismatch.");
    }
}
```

This is the definition:

```
struct AddressFamily {
    static const Forge::Int Unspecified = AF_UNSPEC;
    static const Forge::Int UNIX = AF_UNIX;
    static const Forge::Int INet = AF_INET;
    static const Forge::Int IPX = AF_IPX;
    static const Forge::Int AppleTalk = AF_APPLETALK;
    static const Forge::Int INet6 = AF_INET6;
};
```

Am I missing something here that's really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
he->h_addrtype != AddressFamily::INet
```

since `INet` is a static member of struct.

Comment: Thank you. Well, problem solved. Sorry @JuanchoPanza, but ForEveR got ahead of you so I'll have to accept his answer.

Comment: @JesseBrands no problem, although my clock has me answering first :-) but I don't care much, the answers are the same.

Answer (score 2):

`INet` is a static member of `AddressFamily` so you need

```
AddressFamily::INet
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try like this to access the static member:

```
AddressFamily::INet
```