# Can an enum be used as a data structure here? Error: "Redefinition of enumerator"

Tags: c++, data-structures, enums

I am trying to calculate temperature from IMU using its gain and offset, and this is how I'd like to retrieve the gain and offset value, so that I know I get the right value from the right type of IMU:

```
float gain = IMU_TEMPERATURE_CHARACTERISTICS::GAIN::type1;
float offset = IMU_TEMPERATURE_CHARACTERISTICS::ZERO_ADC_OFFSET::type1;
```

So I created this data structure

```
struct IMU_TEMPERATURE_CHARACTERISTICS
{
    enum GAIN
    {
        type1 = 4,
        type2 = 256
    };

    enum ZERO_ADC_OFFSET
    {
        type1 = 15,
        type2 = 20
    };
};
```

However, my IDE complains

```
Redefinition of enumerator 'type1' previous definition is here
```

and obviously about `type2` as well

```
Redefinition of enumerator 'type2' previous definition is here
```

which complains about the `type1` and `type2` defined in `ZERO_ADC_OFFSET`.

I am wondering how should I change my data structure, or even what data structure I should use in this scenario?

Comment: Offtopic: do not use ALL CAPS symbol names for anything else then macro.

Comment: `flaot` and `enum` is strange thing `float gain = IMU_TEMPERATURE_CHARACTERISTICS::GAIN::type1;`

Comment: What those `type1` and `type2` symbols represents. Note that note everyone have proper knowledge in this domain.

Comment: This would work with scoped enums aka `enum class`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl this was my thought too, but he do something strange with this values.

Comment: Enum is not a data structure.

Comment: This isn't really a data structure at all since nothing is put in memory at runtime. It's just a way of naming constant values.

Comment: Dupe : [Redefinition and Enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772253/redefinition-and-enumerator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are requiring with first snippet of code, which I'll shorten to this

```cpp
float gain = imu::gain::type1;
float offset = imu::offset::type1;
```

is essentially to have 4 numbers and be able to access them via two levels of naming, each of which has 2 possible alternatives.

I also suspect that you have been silent about the fact that those 4 numbers are actually 4 constants, in the sense there will be never other values then those 4 in your program.

If the above is true, then you could be happy with just having nested namespaces:

```cpp
namespace imu {
namespace gain {
double type1 = 4;
double type2 = 256;
}
namespace offset {
double type1 = 15;
double type2 = 20;
}
}
```

which will allow the same syntax you asked for.

Anyway, whether my hypothesis  on your intentions is correct or not, I agree you're putting the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you organized symbols in strange way (cart before the horse).

Consider change this into this form

```cpp
struct ImuTempretureCharacteristic {
   double gain;
   double offset;
};

constexpr ImuTempretureCharacteristic type1{4, 15};
constexpr ImuTempretureCharacteristic type2{256, 20};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Redefinition of enumerator 'type1' previous definition is here

Enums don't work the way you think they do. `enum class`es do, though, scope-wise at least. You need to study up on C-style `enum`s, and C++ `enum class`es.

> I am wondering how should I change my data structure, or even what data structure I should use in this scenario?
>
> Some sample code is highly appreciated.

You could also just "namespace" this with names in the constants, separated by an underscore:

```cpp
// Definitions

constexpr float IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_GAIN_TYPE1 = 4;
constexpr float IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_GAIN_TYPE2 = 256;

constexpr float IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_ZERO_ADC_OFFSET_TYPE1 = 15;
constexpr float IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_ZERO_ADC_OFFSET_TYPE2 = 20;

// Usage

float gain = IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_GAIN_TYPE1;
float offset = IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_ZERO_ADC_OFFSET_TYPE1;
```

### Packaging up grouped constants into a struct

But this `struct` approach is better, and what I'd prefer to use:

```cpp
// Definitions

struct ImuTempCharacteristics 
{
    float gain;
    float offset;
};

constexpr ImuTempCharacteristics IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_TYPE1 = {4, 15};
constexpr ImuTempCharacteristics IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_TYPE2 = {256, 20};

// Usage

float gain = IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_TYPE1.gain;
float offset = IMU_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS_TYPE1.offset;
```